# Beth one equal to beth two not known?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram Alpha seems to say that ($\beth_1=\beth_2$) is unknown, but i'm pretty sure that $\beth_2$ is greater than $\beth_1$ ? is this just a bug in WA or is there a way in set theory that you can make them equal ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\beth_1$ is the cardinality of the reals; $\beth_2$ is the cardinality of the power set of the reals, and is strictly bigger. I think this "unknown" is "WolframAlpha doesn't know", rather than that humanity does not know.